# Filegeodatabase fanout

Tags: fme-form

I tried to fanout data but it is all in the same FGDB. So, is it possible to do this? I need to write data for every time different amount of different area into different, but schematic same filegeodatabse.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do a fanout to different geodabase.

You have 2 different types of fan out operations in FME (as I can recall, it's been a year or 2 since I've used it).

Your first is a Dataset Fanout.  This will allow you to spread your data across multiple datasets based on an attribute (in this case your dataset is your File Geodatabase).  The option is found by a right click in the Navigation pane on our File Geodatabase writer

The other is the feature class fan out (I cant remember the FME name for it), but I'm guessing this is the Fanout feature you're using now.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Correct. This page on fmepedia explains (http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Fanout). It sounds like you are using a Feature Type fanout (in the Properties dialog) when you need to use a Dataset fanout (in the Navigator window)

Comment: Thanks Mark.  It's been a while since I've used FME.  It's a good piece of kit!

Comment: Another feature worth considering is dynamic schema: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Dynamic-Schema-Examples-FME2011

Comment: I knew that all you mentioned. That was my mistake, because 29 of 30 workbenches with fanout option set to YES has YES, and the 1 didn't have it becuase I forgot to do this. The funniest thing is that all fanout testing I did was with fme wb which has fanout NO. Mea culpa :) Everything works fine now. However thank to all of you, especially Mark I. and blah238 who are always answering to my questions and issues.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem may be that you're thinking of a fGDB the same was as you think of a shapefile.

In a shapefile you've got one single file which contains all features of a certain `feature type` (as FME calls them). When you fan-out you get multiple shapefiles, each with a different feature type in them

However, fGDB's are more like databases. They themselves contain multiple `feature classes` (what ArcGIS calls them) and each of these Feature Classes contains the actual data.
So you should be getting multiple feature classes within the same fGDB when you use the fan-out for fGDB.

If you want multiple fGBD's, you'll need to use multiple writers and fan-out earlier in the workspace using a `FeatureTypeFilter` transformer.